# Unique string regex match RE2

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy, re2

I have a regular expression which works with Javascript, however I am unable to use it with `RE2` as it uses RE2 to compile the query. `RE2` does not support negative afterlook or ?! - which is why it doesn't work.

The regex is supposed to match all unique strings that follow the pattern.
How can the regex be changed so that it works with RE2?

```
a: (\w+\b)(?!.*\b\1\b)

input: `a: hello a: hello a: hello_world`

output (single matches): ["a: hello", "a: hello_world"]
```

Comment: That's not possible without lookarounds, which aren't supported in the stdlib regex implementation.

Comment: my $0.02: `regex` is fine for scripting languages... but for compiled functional languages like `go`, there's usually an easier way.